# wxPython SetMinSize seems to set size explicitly, not allows window to grow when needed

Tags: python, wxpython

Considering the code below. I create a `StaticText` on which I set a Minimum size. However, the `StaticText` always gets this size as the actual size. Even though the text does not fit. Am I doing something wrong here ?

I want to use this functionality to create a key-value display with proper alignment of the values and only expanding the `key` part if needed:

```
a key       - the value
another key - another value
a big key which does not fit - this value
the key     - the value
```

```py
import wx


class TestPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()

        static_text = wx.StaticText(
            parent=self, label="a long label exceeding min size."
        )
        static_text.SetMinSize(wx.Size(50, -1))

        sizer.Add(static_text)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frm = wx.Frame(None, title="Test MinSize")
    pnl = TestPanel(frm)
    frm.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be want to you want to hear but here goes.

The sizer performs a dance between the programmers desire to display data and the variable nature of that data. Additionally it has to cope with that pesky external thing we refer to as the `user`, who has a habit of resizing windows.

SetMinSize is an instruction to the sizer, a hint if you like, on what it should attempt to do automatically. Most controls will also set the minimal size to the size given in the control’s constructor, as a `best guess`.

These instructions can be overridden or adjusted with the `proportion` and `flag` values of the sizer entry for that control.
Always keep in mind that other controls within the same sizer will be affected, which can have undesirable results on presentation.

If we give the sizer the `wx.EXPAND` flag for that control, it will show the whole widget whilst keeping the MinSize. In this case, expanding it vertically.

If we give the sizer a proportion of 1 it will stretch it as much as it can in the direction of the sizer, relative to other controls sharing that sizer.

To appreciate what goes on, it's best to play with code like this, altering the `MinSize`, `proportion` and `flags`, testing each change, until the voodoo of sizers becomes slightly less obscure.

Note: In addition, also test re-sizing the window, to see what happens in each scenario.

Additional testing notes:

- Test sizers with more than 1 control or widget
- Assign colours to highlight what isn't always obvious.
- 

```
import wx

class TestPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        static_text = wx.StaticText(
            parent=self, label="a long label exceeding min size.")
        static_text2 = wx.StaticText(self, label="another label")
        static_text.SetBackgroundColour('green')
        static_text.SetMinSize(wx.Size(50, -1))

        sizer.Add(static_text, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL, border=0)
        sizer.Add(static_text2, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frm = wx.Frame(None, title="Test MinSize", size=(300,100))
    pnl = TestPanel(frm)
    frm.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Examples for the above code:
[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Comment: Many thanks for this elaborate answer! Indeed it is not exactly what I wanted to hear tbh. I really laughed out loud on the voodoo thing! That's exactly what it feels like sometimes.

What you're basically doing here is playing with the proportions of the sizers. And I don't think adding SetMinSize does anything helpful here

Comment: @sanders The examples are a bit more subtle that just playing with the proportion flag but Yes, the `SetMinSize` only tells the sizer to attempt to reserve a certain amount for that particular widget. The gist of the answer, was, sizers appear to be sneaky beasts and often it pays to play around with a tame one, lest a wild one bites you in the behind. They have a habit of attacking the unwary and ill-prepared. Herding cats, springs to mind.

Comment: You're absolutely right with them being sneaky beasts. Sometimes to much frustration to be honest.